# Django csrf token missing or incorrect error 403

Tags: python, django, csrf

When i submit the form i get following error:

> CSRF verification failed
>
> Reason given for failure:
>
> ```
> CSRF token missing or incorrect.
> ```

my views.py is:

```
def name(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
        form=NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name=form.cleandata['your_name']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/',RequestContext(request))

    else:
        form=NameForm()
    return render_to_response('contact.html')
```

my setting.py file:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

my forms.py file is:

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name=forms.CharField(initial='your name',max_length=100)
```

my contact.html is:

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^search/$', search),url(r'^contact/$',contact),
url(r'^name/$',name),url(r'^your-name',name),url(r'^thanks/$',thank)
]
```

Comment: `return render_to_response('contact.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))` add this line insted of `return render_to_response('contact.html')`

Comment: I don't know a lot about django, but the basic idea of csrf is a value stored in the session and then sent to the form to evaluate it on submitting.

i.e Checkout your session settings and be sure that it works fine.

Comment: The context_instance parameter in render_to_response was deprecated in Django 1.8, and removed in Django 1.10.    when using getting error  :render_to_response() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function to render the template, instead of the [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response).

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def name(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['your_name']
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/', RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

Comment: now it is working but showing error as :                                              'ContactForm' object has no attribute 'cleandata'

Comment: Use `form.cleaned_data['your_name']`. There is no attribute named `cleandata`, its `cleaned_data`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@csrf_protect` decorator. 
You can get details about csrf [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/)

Comment: i did add it above name(request) method as : @csrf_protect still not working

Comment: from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.shortcuts import render

@csrf_protect
def my_view(request):
    c = {}
    # ...
    return render(request, "a_template.html", c)

Answer (score 0):

`csrf Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)` when submitting a request:

In a form, include `{% csrf_token %}`, which generates an input tag with the csrf token value, and in the request, have the headers include X-CSRFTOKEN

```
headers: {
  content_type: 'application/json',
  'X-CSRFToken': "{{ csrf_token }}"
},
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/